# How do I create a shortcut to IPython's interactive shell on the dock?

Tags: dock, command-line, python

I have successfully installed IPython. I can open the interactive shell by typing this from the Terminal:

```
ipython qtconsole &
```

Is there a way to create a shortcut on the dock that executes the command above?

Answer (score 1):

Open AppleScript Editor (/Applications/Utilities) and type this:

```
do shell script "open 'ipython qtconsole &'"
```

Save it as an application and add it to the dock.